# Find the anti-symmetric matrix associated with the vector $\bar{v}= (2, −3, 1)$.

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Find the anti-symmetric matrix associated with the vector $\bar{v}= (2, −3, 1)$.

How to find such matrix? Please suggest the method.

A is anti-symmetric if $A^T=-A$. But how to find $A$ associated to a vector?

Comment: What is your definition of "the anti-symmetric matrix associated with a vector" $v\in\Bbb R^3$? Some people would refer to the linear transformation $T(x)=v\times x$. Your question is totally vague, as it stands.

Comment: @TedShifrin With $T(x)=v\times x$, how to solve the problem..The answer given by Dr. Sundar below is correct but don't know how it is defined.

Comment: Look up how to write the matrix of a linear transformation. Do not just post homework questions and expect us to do them all (even though some people will oblige).

Comment: @TedShifrin understand the definition ...thanks

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $v$ is the vector
$$
v = \left[ \matrix{ v_1 \cr v_2 \cr v_3 \cr} \right]
$$

Then an anti-symmetrix matrix $A$ associated with $v$ can be defined as
$$
A = \left[ \matrix{ 0 & -v_3 & v_2 \cr
         v_3 & 0 & -v_1 \cr
 -v_2 & v_1 & 0 \cr} \right]
$$

You may substitute values for $v_1, v_2, v_3$ to answer your query.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks. But what is the definition of such matrix?